# Regular Expression to insert a line before a filename

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to insert a line before a filename, so I just want to search for *.html and insert a line before that.

The file is large and looks like this:.

Example:

```
<a href="file1.html" class="xxx">
<a href="file2.html" class="xxx">
<a href="file3.html" class="xxx">
```

I want to search and replace it with:

```
<a href="..\source1\source2\source3\file1.html" class="xxx">
<a href="..\source1\source2\source3\file2.html" class="xxx">
<a href="..\source1\source2\source3\file3.html" class="xxx">
```

Does someone know how?

Comment: Why don't you just use the standard Find/Replace function (CTRL+H)? Find: `href="xxx.html"` Replace with:`href="..\source1\source2\source3\file.html"`

Comment: Note: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered.

Comment: Sorry for that. Did not mean to mislead anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am trying to insert text before a filename.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `file`
- Set "Replace with" to `..\\source1\\source2\\source3\\file`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Disable "matches newline"

  [image]

**Example before**:

```
<a href="file1.html" class="xxx">
<a href="file2.html" class="xxx">
<a href="file3.html" class="xxx">
```

**Example after**:

```
<a href="..\source1\source2\source3\file1.html" class="xxx">
<a href="..\source1\source2\source3\file2.html" class="xxx">
<a href="..\source1\source2\source3\file3.html" class="xxx">
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)